# Grouping and Summing a List in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list in C# e.g.

```
A,1
B,2
C,3
A,4
B,5
```

I want to return the result in a list as:

```
A,5
B,7
C,3
```

So grouping by the first column and summing the second.

How do I do this? Happy to use LINQ. Declaration and code so far as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyList> list = new List<MyList>();

        list.Add(new MyList() { Letter = "A", Value = 1 });
        list.Add(new MyList() { Letter = "B", Value = 2 });
        etc... 
    }
}

class MyList
{
    public string Letter { get; set; }
    public long Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is the List two-dimensional? Like a `List<List<int>>`?

Comment: And do you want a solution in LINQ only? Because otherwise the solution is trivial..

Comment: _I have a list in C#_ - then post the declaration, at the very least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
var results = list.GroupBy(x => x.Letter, x => x.Value)
                  .Select(g => new { Letter = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum() });
```

(It's not clear what your types are, but hopefully you'll get the needed list from this.)

There's an overload of `GroupBy` which will let you do all of this in one call, but I personally find the above version simpler.

Answer (score 3):

```
var results = data.GroupBy(item => item.Letter)
.Select(group => new
{
  Letter = group.Key,
  Count = group.Sum(item => item.Value),
});
```

Just replace `Letter` with whatever property gives you "A", "B", "C", etc. and `Value` with whatever gives you 1, 2, 3, etc.  If `A,1` is a string, not a class with two properties, then you'll need to parse that string.